# How to fix the hosting address in Flask ngrok

Tags: python, flask, ngrok

I'm using an API from my computer as a server via flask ngrok, which generates an address where users can remotely use my API, however every time I run my api it generates a random address like this: `http://1b1c-187- 121-198-62.ngrok.io`
How do I generate a fixed address?

This is my main code:

```
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

#app = Flask(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates')
run_with_ngrok(app)   #starts ngrok when the app is run


UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/'
 
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
 
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
        
########################################
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
          
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():                       
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        #return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        #return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        #file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'foto.jpeg'))

        #### Padronizando tamanho de foto
        basewidth = 400
        # My image is a 200x374 jpeg that is 102kb large
        foo = Image.open('./static/foto.jpeg')
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(foo.size[0]))
        # I downsize the image with an ANTIALIAS filter (gives the highest quality)
        hsize = int((float(foo.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        foo = foo.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        foo = ImageOps.exif_transpose(foo)
        foo.save("./static/fase1/foto.jpeg",optimize=True,quality=95)
        #foo.save("./static/foto2.jpeg", optimize=True,quality=50)
        #########

        #### Meu código
        #os.remove('./static/foto.png')
        #os.remove('./static/uploads/foto2.png')
        os.system('python evala.py --trained_model=./weights/yolact_plus_resnet50_meat_3700_495900.pth --config=yolact_resnet50_meat_config --score_threshold=0.8 --top_k=100 --images=./static/fase1:./static/mask')
        #### 
        # get directory path where you want to save the images
          #print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')
        return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/foto2.jpeg'), code=301)

app.run()
```

OBS: My code won't work, it's just to show about the base of my code.

Comment: I think for that you have to pay. I also came accross the same problem long time back, I resolved it by getting one static endpoint from pythonanywhere.com and whenever the ngrok server restarts it just tells the python anywhere server the new endpoint. you can check it here https://github.com/epsi95/Sharefi

Comment: Custom domain names require a paid plan.

Comment: But I'm using my PC as a server, I need just a fixed adress... But thans for your time. 
=)

Comment: I'd suggest using [pyngrok](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#open-a-tunnel) instead of `flask-ngrok`, as it gives you a lot more flexibility. Others are correct that what you're asking for requires a paid plan, but grab the `public_url` returned from [connect](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.connect) and you can automate your workflow such that the changing URL won't be an issue for your application.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others before, that requires a [paid plan](https://ngrok.com/pricing) that will give you custom domains and reserver domains.

For a free alternative, you can request a subdomain (`-s`) with [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.github.io/www/).